# Can I export from draw.io to a multipage PDF?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have a large diagram in draw.io.  The draw window shows pagebreaks, but when I export to PDF a just get a one-page PDF with very large page size.

Is there a way to export a diagram to a multipage PDF?

Comment: I have the opposite problem! My diagram is split across pages and no longer makes sense, and I can't find a setting to change it. I guess they flipped the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try printing the diagram using File, Print and then print that to a PDF using the browser's built-in print functionality (works on Macs, needs a PDF printer driver in Windows).

Comment: Good workaround.  As a Mac user I should have thought of that earlier!